# Use Guzzle in Laravel package development

Tags: php, laravel

Recently i am working on a package for Laravel.

I am at beginner level on Laravel Package Development.

I need to use [Guzzle Client](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/) for an API request from this package.

If i use use `GuzzleHttp\Client;` in my controller, it's showing class not found. (I know why. because it's outside of app folder and not autoloaded for this path)

Now, how can i use guzzle inside of my custom package controller.

Here what i wanting:

**This is my controller method:**

```
 public function packageList($vendor, $type)
    {
        $client = new Client();
        $result = $client->get('https://packagist.org/packages/list.json?vendor='.$vendor.'&type='.$type, [
            'form_params' => [
                'sample-form-data' => 'value'
            ]
        ]);

        dd($result);
    }
```

I attached classes of Guzzle

```
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
```

Getting Exception:

```
Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found
```

Comment: https://medium.com/laravel-5-the-right-way/using-guzzlehttp-with-laravel-1dbea1f633da

Comment: The same way as in a "regular" controller I guess. https://laravel.com/docs/master/http-client Are you having problems?

Comment: can't find the class , because it's outside of app directory

Comment: Laravel's HTTP  client uses Guzzle, have you read that link I posted? And followed the installation instructions?

Comment: Kindly add the guzzle service provider to your boot or register method.

Comment: Can you share the code in question? This would help a lot to identify the problem

Comment: @kerbholz should i install guzzle in my package directory or root ?

Comment: Add it to your package's `composer.json`.

Comment: awesome. class found on the controller. this was the issue. thanks brother

Comment: @kerbholz so that was solved by this way : i had to registered the dependency on my package composer.json file and for development purpose i had to install it on main (root path) composer.json file. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Found this answer on stack with the same question

Open up your terminal at the root of your project and enter

`composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle`

It worked for the mailgun API. For some reason, the suggested method at the laravel's mail doc. You may install this package to your project by adding the following line to your composer.json file

`"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.3|~6.0"`

doesn't make the composer download the Guzzle source codes. By the way, I didn't find out what | means in determining the version. This command just downloads the PSR code.

In this moment, the solution may work. However, be aware of compatibility issues. Because the command would install the latest stable version, not the suitable one.

answer by: shampoo

if this doesnt help, try reading the docs : http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html

Comment: Laravel have already guzzle installed. i am developing the package. so if someone install this package on their environment then how they will know it's need guzzle